# What is the best way to edit a node library file?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using oauth to our corp github using passport. Since the available passport library files are pointing to github.com , I had to change the library file to point to our corp url.  If I checkin the library file they will get overwritten when I do an npm install. What is the ideal way to maintain such edited library files.

Comment: Surely there's gotta be a better way than editing the library file. Care to give an example of what you had to change? a link to the line in github would be sufficient, along with an excerpt in the question. If changing it directly in the code is the only option, you're options are very limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [`passport-github`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github), reading the source would provide you with some clues on how to change the URL's (specifically [these lines](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/blob/af8bad0041f7b8e902af3d81cbe6f197d825eb55/lib/strategy.js#L53,L54)):

```
options.authorizationURL = options.authorizationURL || 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize';
options.tokenURL = options.tokenURL || 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token';
```

In other words:

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
  authorizationURL : 'your authorization url',
  tokenURL         : 'your token url',
  ...
}, ...);
```